# Docker swarm regionalization for latency sensitive topology

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

We are currently operating a backend stack in central europe, Japan and Taiwan and are perparing our stack to transition to docker swarm.

We are working with real time data streams from sensor networks to do fast desaster warnings which means that latency is critical for some services. Therefore, we currently have brokers (rabbitmq) running on dedicated servers in each region as well as a backend instance digesting the data that is sent accross these brokers.

I'm uncertain how to best achieve a comparable topology using docker swarm. Is it possible to group nodes, let's say by nationality and then deploy a latency critical service stacks to each of these groups? Should I create separate swarms for each region (feels conceptually contradictory to docker swarm)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The swarm managers should be in a low latency zone. Swarm workers can be anywhere. You can use a node label to indicate the location of the node, and restrict your workloads to a particular label as needed.

Latency critical considerations on the container-to-container network across large regional boundaries may be relevant depending on your required data path. If the only latency-critical data path is to the rabbitmq service that is external to the swarm, then you won't need to worry about the container-to-container latency.

It is also a valid pattern to have one swarm per region. If you need to be able to lose any region without impacting services on another region, then you'd want to split it up. If you have multiple low latency regions, then you can spread the master nodes across those.

Comment: If you have any references explaining this topology I'd love to see them. Im running swams at several geographically distributed sites and performance was horrid.
I think I did have managers at both sites because I was treating them like availability zones.

Comment: I mean, if this actually works, and is not regarded as an anti pattern, I'd really like to get the protection afforded by dockers vxlans so I dont have to bridge things over public internet to exposed ports between sites.

Comment: @ChrisBecke [Swarm uses the raft algorithm for consensus](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/raft/) between the managers. Anything using raft is particularly sensitive to high latency between the nodes. (think about running mysql in master-master mode with lots of latency and waiting for consistency confirmation before allowing more changes to the database). Any swarm object (service, network, config, secret, etc) needs to be written to the swarm database.

I tried to find a good reference on this, but my quick search in the docker docs didn't show anything.

Comment: I have a multi site setup and read as much of dockers own docs as I could. Their docs on service placement constraints implied geographically spanning swarms were possible as their use case was a node.label.region=us-east example. But I could never find any public documents describing best practices for setting up swarm at scale. Perhaps this was kept as secret sauce for EE customers!? Anyway, thanks so much for the insight.